# How to prevent of supplanting (moving) element when there is border on hover?

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML structure like this:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li:hover {
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

As you see, when `:hover` runs, the position of `<li>` changes. How to keep it constant (fix)?

**Note:**  I can do that using `box-shadow`, But I don't want. Because the most of my website's visitors use old browsers. Well, is there any alternative solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a transparent border to each `li` element.

This will displace the border that is added on hover.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
li {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}
li:hover {
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: WTF. that's really tricky. You are much clever. good for you. +1

Comment: alternatively, 2px margin + 0px border on the plain element, 0px margin + 2px border on the hovered.

Comment: @MarcB WTF again !!!! Why I didn't think about your solution. You are much clever too.

Comment: Well, can you please give me a hint? Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0bm4wq7h/20/).. I want a constant position for `div` ever. As you see in fiddle, I added some margin for doing that but still there is *move* when border shows and hides. How to fix it? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using `outline` is a simple alternative.

```css
ul{
list-style:none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
}

li:hover{
outline: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You know what? before asking, I thought there is no solution for my question, but now ...! Thanks +1

Answer (score 1):

Set a default border on the child elements that matches the background colour of the parent element (or is transparent) and then just change the border colour on hover.

```css
ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
li{
    border:2px solid #fff;
}
li:hover{
    border-color:#000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Another solution would be to set the `line-height` and left `padding` of the child elements and reduce them on hover and, like so:

```css
ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
li{
    line-height:24px;
    padding:0 0 0 7px;
}
li:hover{
    border:2px solid;
    line-height:20px;
    padding:0 0 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Updated answer with an alternative solution for you, @stack.

Comment: You know what? before asking, I thought there is no solution for my question, but now ...! If I could I give you +1 again.

Comment: I have a similar problem, Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0bm4wq7h/20/).. I want a constant position for div ever. As you see in fiddle, I added some margin for doing that but still there is move when border shows and hides. How to fix it? tnx

Comment: @Shafizadeh, don't change the margin in your JavaScript, just set the [`box-sizing` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) of you `div` to `border-box`. Doing so will include the border within the dimensions you have specified. http://jsfiddle.net/0bm4wq7h/22/